# Let users change layout and design in CMS/webshop

Tags: jquery, css, asp-classic, content-management-system, webshop

I have a web shop system built in classic ASP which contains several web shops in one system. Different users of this system can change their web shop CSS-file to be able to get the design changes they like. However, now we want to build more advanced designs/layouts for the users to switch between. And with user I mean the web shop owners.

What would be the best approach to this? We have classic ASP functions that inserts different functions like the order form, product listings and such but now I need to move around stuff in the code base to get the layout changes I need.

I was thinking about a JQuery script at the bottom of the page that is unique for every web shop in the system. Then I would be able to modify the code base and style it with CSS. That would be a solution but I'm not sure if it's a good idea to do it this way. Are there any other options other then to rebuild everything from scratch?

Best Regards